# Why does using the "less than" operator in SQLITE give me erroneous results when all my entries are integer?

Tags: sqlite

Im using SQLITE and the operator "<"  is not working.

I dont know why

```
SELECT us_PORCENTAJE,CALCULO,(us_PORCENTAJE-CALCULO) FROM CTRL_CH_FEE_PORCENTAJE WHERE  (CAST(us_PORCENTAJE AS INT) - CAST(CALCULO AS INT))<1;
```

The output is:

50|50|0

25|25|0

10|10|0

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFloV.png)

Comment: Well 0 is less than 1, which is what your `WHERE` clause is filtering.  I expect your current output.

Comment: Is an error, Please delete my question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.